# overwriting a part of a session

Tags: php

i have a session looking like this:

```
        array(1) {
  [31]=>
  array(10) {
    ["aantal"]=>
    int(1)
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "31"
    ["filmtitel"]=>
    string(16) "2_fast_2_furious"
    ["film_id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["zaal_id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["dag"]=>
    string(8) "woensdag"
    ["zaaltitel"]=>
    string(6) "zaal 1"
    ["tijdstip"]=>
    string(8) "17:30:00"
    ["stoeltjes"]=>
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      string(2) "20"
      [1]=>
      string(2) "21"
      [2]=>
      string(2) "22"
    }
    ["aantalStoeltjes"]=>
    string(3) "150"
  }
}
```

my question is, how can i overwrite the content of `["stoeltjes"]`?

when i do `unset($_SESSION['addToCart'][$id]["stoeltjes"]);`

then `["stoeltjes"]`gets deleted but when i add other values they get put in an extra array inside the stoeltjes array.

I assign the new values ass following: `$_SESSION["addToCart"][$id]["stoeltjes"][] = $seats;`

Comment: Could you show us the code where you intend to assign values to other indexes of the $_SESSION array? Also, there is no `addToCart` index in your var_dump so where does it come from?

Comment: Could you edit your post and add code on how you assign the new values.

Comment: @erisco, just because i vardumped the content of addToCart

Comment: According to your edit, you are very explicitly telling PHP to recreate an array under "stoeltjes". Perhaps you just want $_SESSION['seats'] = $seats; ?

Comment: @erisco, after reading your comment i found the mistake, i shouldnt have added the last square brackets

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$_SESSION['addToCart'][$id]["stoeltjes"] = "new value";
```

should do it.

Answer (score 2):

Lets say you want to put 25 in ["stoeltjes"] then, do it like this:

```
 $_SESSION['addToCart'][$id]["stoeltjes"] = 25;
```

Answer (score 1):

the extra `[]` tells the code that you want a new array element in your variable.

doing this:

```
$_SESSION["addToCart"][$id]["stoeltjes"][] = "new value";
$_SESSION["addToCart"][$id]["stoeltjes"][] = "new value";
$_SESSION["addToCart"][$id]["stoeltjes"][] = "new value";
```

is equivalent of doing this:

```
$_SESSION["addToCart"][$id]["stoeltjes"][0] = "new value";
$_SESSION["addToCart"][$id]["stoeltjes"][1] = "new value";
$_SESSION["addToCart"][$id]["stoeltjes"][2] = "new value";
```